# How to read Putty.exe (but not plink.exe) output in C#?

Tags: c#, putty

I wish to know how to read the output from putty.exe console window.

There are plenty of answers about how to get the output (and how to input) for plink.exe/cmd.exe, yet none of them work for putty.exe.

FYI this is what i have now; changing the string 'putty.exe' to 'cmd.exe' make things work:

```
            var process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "putty.exe";
            process.OutputDataReceived +=
                (s, e) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
                    switch (e.Data)
                    {
                        case "test1":
                            {
                                process.StandardInput.WriteLine("echo test2");
                            }
                            break;

                        case "test2":
                            {
                                process.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                };

            if (process.Start())
            {
                process.BeginErrorReadLine();
                process.BeginOutputReadLine();
                process.StandardInput.WriteLine("echo test1");
                process.WaitForExit();
            }
```

Edited:
The purpose to the piece of code is to automatically handle the login process: after username/password are provided, enter 'sudo' and input corresponding auditing messages.
I need a way to capture the output of putty.exe so that I could input texts to this terminal.

Comment: Why not use sshnet.codeplex.com instead?

Comment: Maybe you should try to explain why you want to read PuTTY output and not plink.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl putty seems more powerful to use interactively as we are not using it for automatic jobs.

Answer (score 2):

The entire point of plink.exe is to give a command-line interface to PuTTY. That is what you're supposed to use.

Comment: putty seems more powerful to use interactively as we are not using it for automatic jobs. besides the team decides to use putty.exe but not plink.exe via cmd.exe

Comment: So, are you automating or not? Perhaps if you add exactly what you're trying to accomplish, we could better help you.

Comment: hi, basically i wish to automate the login and auditing process only; end user will then go to the terminal and do any further actions.

Comment: Yeah, you're trying to fit a round AND square peg in a round hole.  I'd suggest taking care of the automation using private keys for authentication and auditing on the server end.  That, though, is the topic for another question.

Comment: Hi Hometoast , Can you help me in automating the unix commands in C# using plink , i have tried plink and i was not able to proceed please refer my question in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27645631/execute-unix-commands-using-putty-in-c-sharp